# Ansible Module to setup redshift users

Tags: ansible, amazon-redshift

Is there any ansible module which helps us to automate the user management for redshift like user,group creation,granting privileges etc.

Comment: Did you think about using Ansible cloudformation module (http://docs.ansible.com/cloudformation_module.html) ? You can pass it a cloudformation stack that has all the config needed for Redshift(http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-redshift-cluster.html)

Comment: I haven't tried yet, but do the postgres roles work for usermgmt? Redshift is basically postgres underneath...

Answer (score 1):

All the Ansible modules are [documented on the ansible.com website](http://docs.ansible.com/modules_by_category.html). Currently there are no modules specifically related to redshift. The closest one would be for [cloudformation](http://docs.ansible.com/cloudformation_module.html).

Answer (score 0):

As Cloudformation can only handle the Redshift resource itself but no users, I've adopted the `postgresql_user` Ansible module and created a Redshift compatible version `redshift_user` https://github.com/philsch/ansible-redshift. We're using it in our project, but please note that it's still a "alpha" version at the moment. Feel free to create an issue if you find a bug.

**Alternatively** you can now also reduce user management overhead by [Using IAM Authentication to Generate Database User Credentials](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/mgmt/generating-user-credentials.html). You still need to predefine useful database *Groups* and *Group-Permissions* so you can grant schema/table permissions to your temporary users, but this should be less overhead than managing a list of users.

Answer (score 0):

If terraform is an option, you could consider using the redshift terraform provider: https://github.com/frankfarrell/terraform-provider-redshift
You can manage databases, users, groups, schemas and schema level permissions for groups with it. Alternatively, all the sql you need for an ansible module to do the same can be seen there. There are quite a few gotchas though! For instance, see this discussion: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/143938/drop-user-in-redshift-which-has-privilege-on-some-object